# Python 3.x - toggling fullscreen in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, toggle, fullscreen

So far, I have a command that makes my window fullscreen. Now, predictably, I want to be able to exit fullscreen also.

This is the code I have:

```
def toggFullscreen(self, win):

    def exitFullscreen(event=None):
        win.withdraw()
        win.deiconify()
        win.overrideredirect(False)
        win.geometry('1024x700')

    w = win.winfo_screenwidth()
    h = win.winfo_screenheight()
    win.overrideredirect(True)
    win.geometry('%dx%d+0+0' % (w, h))
    win.focus_set()
    win.bind('<Escape>', exitFullscreen)
```

But the issue is that I can't get the window frame to reappear. I thought that doing `win.overrideredirect(False)` would work, but it didnt.

Answer (score 1):

not sure why it isn't working on your computer, but try this code sample:

```
#!python3

import tkinter as tk

geom=""

def fullscreen():
    global geom
    geom = root.geometry()
    w = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    h = root.winfo_screenheight()
    root.overrideredirect(True)
    root.geometry('%dx%d+0+0' % (w, h))

def exitfullscreen():
    global geom
    root.overrideredirect(False)
    root.geometry(geom)

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Button(root,text ="Fullscreen", command=fullscreen).pack()
tk.Button(root,text ="Normal", command=exitfullscreen).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

the one thing i'm making sure i do is to store the geometry before going fullscreen, and then re applying it when i exit fullscreen. the global statement was needed because if i didn't use it the `fullscreen` function stored the geometry in a local variable instead of the one i created at the top.

Comment: Am interesting approach, but it seems a little complex for something that I feel should be rather simple.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `overrideredirect` flag *before* calling `withdraw` and `deiconify`.

Comment: Is this OS related behavior? On my Windows machine the code in the question works fine, even if I take out `withdraw` and `deiconify` completely.

Comment: This makes sense. I'm working at the moment, but will mark as the answer once I've tried it.