# Cant exit fullscreen on tkinter window python

Tags: python, tkinter, binding, fullscreen

Im trying to make this window fullscreen, then be able to escape with any key. I can't bind the escape key to actually escaping the window, can't figure out where it's going wrong from other similar posts too.

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

root.overrideredirect(True)
root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))
root.focus_set()
root.bind("<Escape>", lambda e: root.quit())

#mybuttonsandframesgohere

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986410/python-3-x-toggling-fullscreen-in-tkinter)

Comment: BTW: you forgot `()` in `mainloop()`

Comment: The method suggested in that link does not cover the menu bar. Yes that was a typo, my apologies

Comment: On some systems (like Linux) `root.overrideredirect` removes window manages (WM) which display border but WM also sends key/mouse events from system to your program. If WM doesn't send event then your program doesn't know that you clicked ESC.

Comment: What is the operating system you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On some systems (like Linux) `root.overrideredirect(True)` removes window manages (WM) which display border but WM also sends key/mouse events from system to your program. If WM doesn't send event then your program doesn't know that you clicked ESC.

This works for me on Linux Mint (based on Ubuntu and Debian). 
Rasbian is base on Debian.

```
import tkinter as tk

def close_escape(event=None):
    print("escaped")
    root.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()

root.overrideredirect(True)
root.overrideredirect(False)

root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
root.focus_set()

root.bind("<Escape>", close_escape)

root.after(5000, root.destroy) # close after 5s if `ESC` will not work

root.mainloop()
```

I put `root.after(5000, root.destroy)` only for test - to close it after 5s if `ESC` will not work.

I use `close_escape` only to see if it was closed by `ESC` or `after()`. If code works then you can use `root.bind("<Escape>", lambda event:root.destroy())`

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.overrideredirect(True)
root.overrideredirect(False)

root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
root.focus_set()

root.bind("<Escape>", lambda event:root.destroy())

root.mainloop()
```

BTW: you may try also without `root.overrideredirect()` - maybe it will works for you

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1) # keep on top
#root.focus_set()

root.bind("<Escape>", lambda event:root.destroy())

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It didn't close on command, but it did close after 5s, but also the print statements were printed out too.

Comment: if it printed `"escaped"` then it should means it closed window with `ESC`.

Comment: one thing to note: Replacing the function close_escape with root.destroy in root.bind does seem to work. Unsure why, but I will just keep the function in there

Comment: I don't understand what is the use of doing `root.overrideredirect(True)` then immediately after `root.overrideredirect(False)`. For me it is the same as not using `overrideredirect` at all.

Comment: Why do you set the flag to `True` then to `False`?  This does not make sense.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ @j_4321  today I see it works for me without `overrideredirect` but previously it needed `root.overrideredirect(True)` to toggle fullscreen. But `root.overrideredirect(True)` turned off events and `bind()` didn't worked, but if you set back `root.overrideredirect(False)` then fullscreen worked and events worked too. Strange situation.

Comment: @j_4321 you are right `bind` sends `event` so it needs `lambda event:root.destroy()`. Corrected in answer.

Comment: It is like writing +1 - 1, so those 2 lines are useless

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ see my previouse comment - `True` and later `False`  looks useless but on some systems (Linux) it was needed to corectly run `fullscreen` and `events`. It seems there is/was issue in `overrideredirect`. Today I see it works on my Linux even without `overrideredirect` but maybe other systems (other linux distributions) still have this problem.

Comment: I never had a problem with using `widnow.attributes("-fullscreen", True)`  on any Windows or Linux distro I used in the past. The problem here is related to combining `geometry()` manager and the `overrideredirect` flag and I believe your post, even if accepted, does not answer the question because: 1. You avoided to face the real problem which I just mentioned and 2. You misused, from 2 perspectives -including the justification pointed by your comment-, the use of that flag.